# How to build a solution with plug-in DLLs that have no explicit "references" to the startup project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My Visual Studio 2013 SLN looks like this:

- Startup.EXE (Refs Core.DLL)
- Core.DLL
- MyPlugin.DLL (Refs Core.DLL)
- MyOtherPlugin.DLL (Refs Core.DLL)

The problem is that it won't compile the two plugin DLLs because there's no link to them from the EXE project. I could include the plugins as references but then the SLN would have to include all plugins rather than just the one or two I'm interested in.

Is there a way to configure the SLN to compile all of the listed DLLs, even when there is no link from the EXE project?

(Update and clarification from comments.)
This means that I could modify the plugin code and press F5, then the plugin DLL will be recompiled. This question is not about getting the DLL loader to see the updated DLLs but just triggering the compiler into action. (Maybe use a post-build=event to copy the DLLs over.)

Comment: Right-click the EXE project > Properties > Build Dependencies > Project Dependencies.  Tick those plug-in projects.

Comment: @HansPassant Many thanks. I was about to give your answer a green tick but its gone.